# databrick job running at same time

Tags: databricks

job 1: run_test [job name]

uses notebook get_num

params: {"num":"1"}

job 2: run_dev

uses notebook get_num

params: {"num":"2"}

when I run both jobs at the same time, the job which runs first parameters gettting applied to second job also. how can I avoid this.

Comment: how do you execute the job?

Comment: I am using rest API to trigger the jobs, fyi. these 2 jobs are running from 2 different job clusters

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Please post the code that submit the job run and job configuration

Comment: I will replicate my case and send you, but its happening

Comment: my bad I was calling one of the master notebook parameter name with extra space so its child notebook falling back to default widget value, thank you so much for helping me out